# Is there any way to get day from date in quicksight?

Tags: data-visualization, analytics, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to get day from date field in quicksight.

Following is date format in quicksight: `2020-09-29T00:00:00.000Z`

I want some function which will parse the date and give the day from this date. `i.e., Tuesday`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the QuickSight Dataset you can define a [Calculated Field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/working-with-calculated-fields.html).

In your case, e.g. `toString(extract('WD',{transaction_date}))`.
[This returns the day of the week as an integer, with Sunday as 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/extract-function.html).
If you need it as a word, you can further translate it with [ifelse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/ifelse-function.html) function.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [formatDate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/formatDate-function.html) to get the day of week as a string i.e. Monday ... `formatDate({datetime}, 'E')`